# "Robust" as a noun

Tags: phrases, expressions

Can an adjective "robust" be a noun in a sentence? And if it can't how would you say with one word "robust fellow" that can be applied to both man and woman? Because as I understand "robust fellow", we say about a man.

Comment: In the same way that we say, "Youth is wasted on the young," we might say "Only the robust should attempt this hike."  But a "robust person" or "robust worker" or something else that makes sense in context could work.

Comment: We can use the definite article to refer to a class. Thus: *the robust* = "those who are robust" (gender not specified). This technique works in a general way for adjectives most of the time.  HTH.

Comment: How about "robust individual" ?That kind of fits both sides of the demographic.

Comment: `a robust person` could be used to refer to a man or a woman

Comment: @Kris But if I am talking about one specific person it doesn't seem to me right to say "He is the robust". What one-word synonym in English language could replace  word-combination written above?

Comment: *I* am the noun form.

Comment: *One* should work. "He is the **robust one**."

Comment: Katherina, you already used "one" in your comment ("I will use this **one**"), well done!

Answer (score 3):

"robust" is an adjective and it could only be used as a noun when you refer to a class ("the robust") just as you say "the poor", "the rich", "the wealthy".  Other adjectives that have a similar meaning are "sturdy", "able-bodied" and "stocky".

> - robust (adj) - strongly formed or built. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/robust)
> - stocky (adj) - compact, sturdy, and relatively thick in build.
> - sturdy (adj) - strong and healthy

These words can be used for both males and females, but I don't think a woman would like to be referred to as "stocky" or "robust".

Answer (score 0):

I would use "stout."

: thick and strong

: physically or materially strong

You could also use "hearty."

: strong, healthy, and active

Definitions from Merriam-Webster

Comment: That's not quite the question we have at hand. Please review the question.

Comment: Actually, this is a part of the question. But as @plmadding wrote definition of "stout" is "thick and strong". And definition of "robust" is "healthy and strong". This two words don't seem like synonyms to me. Or am I wrong?

Comment: They are similar but not exactly the same.  I mentioned them both because I don't know exactly what context you will use the word.  Hearty is a word used to describe women frequently here, in Kansas.  Especially women who have grown up on or currently live on farms.